# PHP get the file name from which the present function is called

Tags: php

I'm trying to come up with a way for a function to know the path of the file that called it. Say I have function f() in file 123.php. I call f() from file abc.php. I want f() to be able to figure out that it was called from abc.php and the path to abc.php.

Please help me out, thanks.

Edit:
 I have a function in test.php which can be called from ajax, something like

```
function getSomething($params){
    check($params);

    check($params);
}
```

It executes one function `check` two times.

I have another function called check() in common.php, something like

```
function check($params){
  //Here, i want know where the file name and line at which it has been called.
}
```

Edit:
Need to get the lines of at which the function has been triggered to check in check function.

It has been executed two times in test.php

First execution-> We need to get test.php, line of first function call

Second execution-> We need to get test.php, line of second function

Answer (score 2):

You need to [obtain a backtrace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) and extract the information from the resulting array. Beware that before PHP/5.4 you were not able to limit how deep the trace goes thus output can be fairly large. It's alright to use it for debugging purposes but I wouldn't abuse it for anything else.

Comment: I've revised the question, please have a look.

Comment: @SrihariGoud I see you've posted an example. What's your doubt?

Comment: You've mentioned AJAX. I hope you aren't looking for the **JavaScript** file and line...

Comment: Its not example, i want know the file name where the function `check` is called from

Comment: just PHP file, I hope you understood the problem

Comment: You can generate a backtrace.

Comment: Any example please, I tried using backtrace. not getting the required result.

Comment: [Here you are](http://es1.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php#example-449).

Comment: Need to get the lines of at which the function has been triggered to check in check function.

It has been executed two times in test.php

First execution-> We need to get test.php, line of first function call

Second execution-> We need to get test.php, line of second function

Comment: To do so, you can generate a backtrace and extract the information from the array it returns.

Answer (score 0):

the constant `__FILE__` contains the filename and full path (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php).　This changes to the included library etc.

What you may want is:

$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] which reflects the currently running script.

Comment: Its gives the file name of the current page, where the function actually exists

Comment: @SrihariGoud see revised answer

Comment: I've revised the question, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You can take alook at debug_backtrace()
https://www.php.net/debug_backtrace.
This function returns an array with all the files

Comment: Its takes the present occurrence.

Comment: @SrihariGoud - Correct, that's what you asked. If you want to obtain all function calls, you can do it with any decent IDE.

Comment: I've revised the question, please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add at parameter to the function signature and pass the constant **FILE** if you want to avoid the potentially expensive debug_backtrace.

Comment: Thanks. But there are more than 100 times,

Comment: You can easily do search and replace.

Comment: if I concluded that there is no solution, then i use like that. thanks